# jQuery selector to hide all TR form table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can someone please tell me which jQuery selector I have to use to hide all `TR` that **does not** contains in `ID="some string"` from a table that have `ID="test"`?

Comment: if you added some HTML that would help - ie the layout that you have with the table / tr  etc

Comment: you cannot specify more then one element with the same id. this is invalid HTML. you should change it and look for a class instead. which will also make it easier to hide them

Answer (score 3):

This works

```
$('#test').find('tr').not('#some_string').hide();
```

See a [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xwMnC/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
$("table#test tr:gt(start_number)").hide();
```

start_numner is number of row after which You want to hide. If want to hide all set it 0

Comment: need to pass table id . Updated now

Comment: Im trying this but its not working

    $('#treeview-table:not(tr[id*="progr"])').each(function(index, value) {
  $(this).hide();
 });

Comment: id tr id which you want to remove is unique then please try other answer posted by me

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $('#test tr').not("#some_string").hide();
```

Live [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bsQH7/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
$('table#test tr#some_string').remove();
```